# Using fsolve with a function with two variables

Tags: python, scipy

My first code is:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    f = np.zeros((5))
    f[0] = -1.0 * x[4] * x[0]
    f[1] = -0.5 * x[4] * (2.0 * x[1] - 2.5) - 1.0 * x[1] + 1
    f[2] = -0.5 * x[4] * (2.0 * x[2] - 2.5) - 1.0 * x[2] + 1
    f[3] = -1.0 * x[4] * x[3]
    f[4] = x[0]**2 + x[3]**2 + 1.5625 * (0.8 * x[1] - 1)**2 + 1.5625 * (0.8 * x[2] - 1)**2
    return f

x0 = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,])
roots = fsolve(func, x0)
print(roots)
```

and my second one is this:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def func(x, l):
    f = np.zeros((5))
    f[0] = -1.0 * l * x[0]
    f[1] = -0.5 * l * (2.0 * x[1] - 2.5) - 1.0 * x[1] + 1
    f[2] = -0.5 * l * (2.0 * x[2] - 2.5) - 1.0 * x[2] + 1
    f[3] = -1.0 * l * x[3]
    f[4] = x[0]**2 + x[3]**2 + 1.5625 * (0.8 * x[1] - 1)**2 + 1.5625 * (0.8 * x[2] - 1)**2
    return f

x0 = np.array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,])
l = 1.
roots = fsolve(func, x0, args=(l))
print(roots)
```

I want to use two variables, I replace `x[4]` with `l`, but in the first code I have this result: `[3.72696991e-59 1.24559962e+00 1.24559962e+00 3.72734991e-59 5.58132193e+01]` and the second code I have `[-7.38465207e-16  1.12686692e+00  1.12686692e+00 -7.38465207e-16 9.31286205e+02]`. What do I need to change in the second code, using two variables, to get the same result from the code 1.

Comment: Before you go too far with your comparison of the two versions, you should deal with the fact that the first version is *failing*.  Add the argument `full_output=True`, and use `roots, info, status, msg = fsolve(func, x0, full_output=True)`, then check `status`.  If `status` is not 1, it means `fsolve` failed.  When I run your code, `status` is 4. (You should also have seen a `RuntimeWarning` when you ran the first version.  Such warnings should not be ignored.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser but that result, isn't it an aproximation?

Comment: `args=(l, )` needs a trailing comma